# How define for Maven's Environment Variable to define Local Repository and Wrapper download location?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-wrapper

I need do mention about Gradle to understand and find the same solution for Maven.

In Gradle exists the `GRADLE_HOME` and `GRADLE_USER_HOME` (repository) *environment variables*, for Maven the former through `M2_HOME` and about the *repository* I use the `settings.xml` file to define the `<localRepository>` location

For both Maven and Gradle I can define in peace the place about where is installed the software, for example other location than `.m2` and `.gradle` to a secondary disk and even with customized directory names. Same goal about the repository location, both for a secondary disk (remember for Maven through the `settings.xml` file)

**Note**: therefore `.gradle` and `.m2` are empty and not used.

In Gradle about the wrapper created, the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file has:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-#.#.#-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Then the final path is: `GRADLE_USER_HOME/wrapper/dists`
Therefore observe how `GRADLE_USER_HOME` (custom location - otherwise `.gradle` by default) is used to define the:

- Local repository
- Base path to install the downloaded Gradle through the wrapper

**Goal**: How accomplish the same behaviour for Maven? I mean, what should be the *environment variable* name (something like `MAVEN_USER_HOME`) for the local repository that Maven should recognize automatically? (**not** using the `settings.xml` file). It with the purpose to have any Maven wrapper installed according that *environment variable* name configured (custom location - otherwise `.m2` by default) and of course defined the Local Repository too.

**Therefore**: I need the `maven-wrapper.properties` using something like `MAVEN_USER_HOME` (custom location - otherwise `.m2` by default) according the developer/user in its machine.

Comment: What is the advantage of *not* using the default place `.m2` in the user directory?

Comment: Have a customized location, and the case the primary disk is running out of space too, is possible have the Local Repository and wrappers distributions in other place from the beginning (pendrive with a high capacity).

Comment: As IO is the main factor in the build, I would put my local repository on an SSD.

Comment: Agree, consider a SSD too, the point is define a different location than the primary disk.

Comment: I have the exact same query as Jordan. I feel that we should answer straight to the point, whether what Jordan asks can or cannot be done, rather than asking him for the advantage, or where he should put the local repository.
Cos if he is ask this question, he definitely has his own reason for not using  the default directory. Even if we convince him that there is no advantage in changing the default place, still it is good to know if Maven has such any constraint in terms of using environment variable to control the local repository location, at least from learning point of view.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I am using spring boot boilerplate code that is generated from `spring.io`. Inside come with `mvnw.cmd`.  By setting `MAVEN_USER_HOME` to a customized location, running `mvnw.cmd` will download the maven to that customized location.

Once done, I still need to manually go to that downloaded maven location to configure the `settings.xml` to point to a customized location for the maven libraries repo.

So at the moment, sadly, seem like the `settings.xml` is required to configure the repo, and `MAVEN_USER_HOME` environment variable has nothing to do with the repo.

Comment: Can you share the part of that source code addition? If you can add more detailed step instructions would be valuable